# Hive table is not showing up in command line interface

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I had a script a to create a hive table, the script is completing successfully but i am unable to see the table, please help.

below is the script to create table
`#!/bin/bash
hive <<! > hive_out.log
create table GoodRecords(
id int,
name string,
state string,
phone_no int,
gender string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as
textfile;
exit;
!`

Logs generated:
`hive> create table GoodRecords(

> id int,
>   name string,
>   state string,
>   phone_no int,
>   gender string) row format delimited fields terminated by ','
>   stored as textfile;
>   hive> exit;`

GUI Hadoop shows that the table had been created:
`/user/hive/warehouse/goodrecords`

Command line output to showtables.
`hive> show tables;
OK
Time taken: 0.34 seconds`

Comment: try to print the table values. select * from GoodRecords

Comment: i had executed above said command but below is a output..


'hive> select * from GoodRecords ;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'GoodRecords''

Comment: create table GoodRecords( id int, name string, state string, phone_no int, gender string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile; try this command from terminal. then run show tables;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue with setting up your Hive Metastore service.

Just try to restart your metastore service. It should work.

Comment: When i am creating a table with a third party software also i am facing same issue.
i could see that the table is created in logs but could not see in CLI but the table exist in hadoop.

Comment: This can happen because you might not have the write access to the temporary folder of your metastore. For example if your metastore is in mysql then grant all priveleges on tmp folder.